# How to increase the thickness of a determinant progress bar?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, windows-phone-8.1

I've added a determinant progress bar to a Windows 8.1 phone app but I don't see a method of increasing the thickness of the progress bar.

I tried to change the thickness by increasing the height property but this has no effect on it's size.

Does anyone have any idea how to increase the height/thickness of the red progress bar?

This is the declaration of the progress bar in my xaml:

```
    <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="False" Maximum="100" Value="30" Width="200" Margin="128,240,128,262"/>
```

[image: Progress Bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to change *ProgressBar*'s 'thickness' just by setting its *Height* property. Just like this:

```
<ProgressBar Height="50" IsIndeterminate="False" Maximum="100" Value="30" Width="200" Margin="128,240,128,262"/>
```

[Here at GitHub](https://github.com/Romasz/WP81RunTime-Examples/tree/master/ProgressBarHeight) you can find a working sample.

In case you need to change more things - you can redefine the *Style* of the *ProgressBar*:

Open designer window, right click on progress bar and then <kbd>Edit Template</kbd>, then create a copy. You should then see a *Style* of your progress bar in resources. In this style you will find *ControlTemplate* and inside there is *Rectangle* with name `ProgressBarIndicator` (at the end):

```
    ... something above
    <Border x:Name="DeterminateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}">
      <Rectangle x:Name="ProgressBarIndicator" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
    </Border>
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

For example you can set the *Height* property of this rectangle and you should achieve your goal.

Comment: I changed the height property of the `ProgressBarIndicator` from the default '4' to '20' but this had no effect on the thickness of the bar. Any other ideas?

Comment: @BrianJ Hmm, as I've tested you should be able to change the height just by *Height* property, without playing with the *Style*. First I wanted to delete my answer, but you marked it as answer, so I've editted it. Can you [check the sample](https://github.com/Romasz/WP81RunTime-Examples/tree/master/ProgressBarHeight)? There is a chance that the problem lies somewhere else - can you share a sample project or more code?